# How to retrieve user information in a placeholder after checking his username in the Wizard?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to develop a simple user management system for the admin of the web application. I am using ASP.NET Wizard Control for this task.
I just put a TextBox for writing the username and when the admin clicks on the Next button, the system should check if the username existed in the database or not. If it is existed, the system should display his information in a placeholder for the admin.

I am struggling with this task. I did the following in the code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Session["Username"] = Username.Text;
    string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=True";
    string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Username = @Username";

    //For checking the user
    if (Request.QueryString["Username"] != null)
    {
        String strUserName = Request.QueryString["Username"];

        ////Check userName Here
        //String strReturnStatus = "false";

        if (CheckUsername(Request.QueryString["Username"]) == true)
        {
            //strReturnStatus = "true";
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(myReader["Name"].ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(myReader["Job"].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        //Response.Clear();
        //Response.Write(strReturnStatus);
        //Response.End();
    }
}

private bool CheckUsername(string username)
{
    string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=True";
    string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Username = '" + username + "'";

    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
         conn.Open(); // Open DB connection.

         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
         {
             int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
             // True (> 0) when the username exists, false (= 0) when the username does not exist.
             return (count > 0);
         }
    }

}
```

**I tried to test this by writing any username in the TextBox, but I did not get any result when I clicked on Next button of the wizard that should redirect me to the placeholder or any control that should display the user information. What I want now is just showing the information of the user if his username existed in the database. How to do that?**

Comment: As a start have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163894.aspx. If it's an internet project then please also read up on sql injection.

Comment: Is you CheckUsername() function returning true for the username you are passing to this page using Request.QueryString["Username"]?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand the concept of page load and postbacks. The code written inside Page_Load will execute every time the page is loaded either by entering the URL in browser or by becuase of button click event. You should place the code that you want to execute only once in

```
if(!isPostback)
{
//code to be need to be executed for the first time
//only goes within this block
}
```

Then as Asken suggested have a look at SQL injection too

Now regarding the problem, in your `Page_Load` event you have:

```
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Username = @Username";
```

You need to set the value of @Username parameter and this is how you can do this:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30); //assumption: UserName column is of varchar type length of 30
nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Username"].Value = strUserName;
```

Comment: What I want is just check the username of the user inside the Wizard control and when I click on the Next button, I should be redirected to another step that contains a Repeater control that shows all the information of that username. I am struggling with this issue. I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am struggling with these many concepts since this my first project on it. I am using Windows Authentication in this project and I am not sure if using QueryString is ok or I should use Session variable. It will be very helpful if you can help me with this issue.

Comment: A very detailed and relevant tutorial is given here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178342.aspx, you can use CreateUserWizard1_NextButtonClick event to check if user exist or not.